# Breaking between/3 based "loop" in SWI-Prolog while maintaining choice points that follow it

Tags: loops, prolog, prolog-cut

I need to iterate over a range of numbers (e.g. using `between/3`) from 1 to `Length` where `Length` is a length of a given list. Iterated number, say `N`, is then applied to a predicate, say `do_something` until it stops failing. That is, `do_something` searches for a correct `N` after which all choice points of `between/3` must be dropped. However, all choice points of `do_something` with proper `N` applied must be executed.

Fist attempt was something like this:

```
% main(+InputList, -N, -OutputList)
main(InputList, N, OutputList) :-
  length(InputList, Length),
  between(1, Length, N),

  % cut all between/3 choice points as soon as Num is instantiated
  freeze(Num, !),

  do_something(InputList, N, OutputList),
  Num is N.
```

This did not work as `freeze/2` doesn't cut `between/3` choice points. A version with `when/2` did not work either. I gather, it is because both `freeze/2` and `when/2` are executed in a separate thread and do not affect the main thread where `between/3` is.

After a while I ended up with the following code that does what's needed, but is inefficient:

```
main(InputList, N, OutputList) :-
  length (InputList, Length),
  between(1, Length, N),
  do_something(InputList, N, _),

  % cut all prior choice points as soon as proper N is found
  !,

  % start do_something over!
  do_something(InputList, N, OutputList).
```

Inefficiency is that `do_something`'s choice point with proper `N` is executed twice. First just before cut, and then once again right after it.

Though this solution works in my case, it is not applicable to a generic case when all `do_something` choice points must be executed only once.

Note that `N` is required to be minimum out of `1..Length` range and is not known in advance. Hence searching for it with `do_something`.

Is there a better solution to this? Is there a way to implement a predicate similar to `between/3` that can stop when signaled somehow? Could there be a specialized builtin predicate that does what's needed? Any fruitful ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: @WillNess, yes, a cut right before `G(N)` and after all G(N) choice points exhausted. In other words, all choice points with proper `N` are needed, but not anything else. Also, I can't see how if-then-else can help here.

Comment: a cut right before G1, you mean? -- I think the posted answer gives a solution, especially if `do_something(...)` was a last goal (otherwise, just put all of them into the `findall` call, like `findall( 1, (do_something(..), ..., ...), Solutions), ...`).

Comment: That will cut all `between/3` choice points before it reaches `G(N)`, right?

Comment: never mind all that, the posted answer seems good.

Comment: (to the curious, there were here some comments of mine with some musings about `*->` but then Paulo posted so I removed them. and then Jan posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `between/3` is a distraction. We don't require it and thus a simple, efficient, and portable solution is possible:

```
main(InputList, N, OutputList) :-
    length(InputList, Length),
    Length >= 1,
    main(1, Length, InputList, OutputList).

main(N, Length, InputList, OutputList) :-
    (   do_something(InputList, N, OutputList) *->
        true
    ;   N < Length,
        M is N + 1,
        main(M, Length, InputList, OutputList)
    ).
```

As in Jan’s solution, it does not evaluate all solutions of `do_something/3` before returning the first, neither does it evaluate the predicate twice. But it also doesn’t require the nasty and non-portable `nb_setarg/2` predicate tricks.

Note that, as Jan remarked, the *soft-cut* control construct, `*->/2`, or its `if/3` meta-predicate variant, can be found in several Prolog systems (including, in one form or the other, CxProlog, Ciao Prolog, ECLiPSe, GNU Prolog, JIProlog, SICStus Prolog, SWI-Prolog, and YAP).

P.S. I keep my first answer as it's more portable and exemplifies a pattern that may be useful for other problems.

Comment: why a distraction? not a distraction. you are *re-implementing* `between` here; you opened up its definition and spliced the next goals into it, so *now* you *can* put the `*->` in, which before that was impossible -- when both `between` and `do_something` were treated as black boxes. isn't it? this is a whole-program transformation. very interesting. :)

Comment: Also, I would agree that `between/3` is not necessary and replacing it with iterative approach is better. As it is stated in the original question, `between/3` is only a method I used to iterate over all possible `N` values, but is not a must have.

Comment: Paulo, thank you again. This is very useful and should perform exactly as needed. I will have to adapt this to suite my case though. I'm accepting this solution instead of your first post.

Answer (score 4):

There is another possibility using [*->/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(*-%3E)/2), which is a variant of ->/2 that does not kill the choice point of the condition.  Now we are not there was we want to kill an *older* choicepoint.  I don't know whether there are Prolog systems that can do so.  Most have provisions to kill all choice points since some mark, but I'm not aware of one that kills a specific one.  So, we must insert a bit of code to conditionally stop further processing.  This results in:

```
main(InputList, N, OutputList) :-
    length(InputList, Length),
    State = state(cont),
    between(1, Length, N),
    (   State = state(cont)
    ->  true
    ;   !,
        fail
    ),
    (   do_something(InputList, N, OutputList)
    *-> nb_setarg(1, State, stop)
    ;   fail
    ).
```

This is totally non-portable, although many systems have *-> (sometimes named if/3) and many have some form of non-backtrackable assignment while if you are desperate you can use assert/retract for that.

See online at [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Psgrxwrq.swinb)

Paulo's answer is certainly more portable.  This should be way faster though and does not evaluate all solutions of `do_something` before returning the first, neither does it evaluate do_something twice.

Comment: Note that my solution **does not evaluate all solutions of between/3**. Likely you mean to write all solutions for the `do_something/3` predicate?

Comment: @PauloMoura Right.  Sorry and fixed.

Comment: Jan, thanks a lot for pointing at `*->` and especially for SWISH examples.

Answer (score 3):

Hoping that I understood your problem description:

```
main(InputList, N, OutputList) :-
    length(InputList, Length),
    between(1, Length, N),
    findall(
        OutputList0,
        do_something(InputList,N,OutputList0),
        OutputLists
    ),
    % cut all prior choice points as soon as proper N is found
    OutputLists = [_|_],
    !,
    member(OutputList, OutputLists).
```

The `findall/3` call will return `Solutions = []` until the `do_something/3` predicate succeeds. When that happens, the `findall/3` call ensures that, for that value of `N`, all the choice points of `do_something(InputList, N, OutputList)` are visited. The following cut then fixes the value of `N` and you can go from there.

**P.S.** Updated with the change you describe in your comment to make it work for your case. There are some non-portable hacks to find only a given number of solutions if you don't want to collect them all.

Comment: Yes, `findall/3` seems to work exactly as needed with small modification of your example. `OutputList` must iterate over all solutions:

   ` findall(Result, do_something(InputList, N, Result), Solutions),`
    
    `Solutions = [_|_],`
    
   ` !,`
    
    `member(OutputList, Solutions).`

Not sure how to use SO markup properly so it appears as multiline code. There are four lines of code here.

Comment: One question though, does `findall/3` create choice points or does it produce entire `Solutions` list first and then advances to the next predicate? Performance wise, the former is preferred as not all `Solutions` may be required. That is only first one or more solutions may be of the interest, not all of them.

Comment: Updated my answer with the change you described in your comment.

Comment: With update, it is now pretty much what I ended up with too, thanks to you hint. What hacks do you have in mind? I’m concerned with performance here. Calling `do_something` twice with its first choice point seems less operations on average compared to always collecting all solutions.

Comment: With `findnsols/4` I'm facing the same issues as before. Either `N` is not known in advance and `between/3` can't be cut as soon as proper `N` is found, or cut right after `findnsols/4` also drops all its choice points. I'm thinking of the solution based on global variable and custom `between/3` which will continue counting until global variable tells it to stop.

Comment: It may be worth looking into an iterative deepening solution where you increment the maximum number of solutions to be collected (after finding `N`) until when know that you have enough solutions.